# How to run c# visual studio project created in ubuntu in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, ubuntu

I've got a problem with Visual Studio console application created in Ubuntu 15.04. When I try to run c# program in Visual Studio in Windows 10 my project doesn't load. How to fix that? I created from hand csproj:

http://pastebin.com/NmLMK0hD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be way easier to just create a new .csproj file with Visual Studio and add your existing Program.cs (:

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders of the project.